# Problem in structuring a proper way to iterate data into html elements in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

What I am trying to do is **:**

Searching for a patient, results in a drop-down list if I choose a user, his gender and phone numbers will be automatically set in their respected fields.

Searching for a user via phone number does the same thing.

HTML Code **:**

```
  <div class="patient-info">
            <h4>Create Appointment</h4>
            <div class="create-app-patient-rating-and-gender">
              <div class="create-app-patient-rating">
                <p>Rating:</p>
                <v-rating
                  v-model="rating"
                  background-color="white"
                  color="yellow accent-4"
                  dense
                  half-increments
                  hover
                  readonly
                  size="18"
                ></v-rating>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div  class="patient-create-data-container" 
           > 
            <!--        v-for="item in gotpatientNames" :key="item.id"            -->
              <v-autocomplete
             @input.native="(event) => fetchPatientnames(event)"
                class="patient-patient"
                v-model="patientname"
                :items="item.patientna"
                hide-no-data
                dense
                filled
                append-icon=""
                label="Patient Name"
              ></v-autocomplete>

              <v-text-field
                v-model="gender"
                show-current
                type="text"
                label="Gender"
              ></v-text-field>
            </div>

            <div class="patient-phones">
              <v-autocomplete
                class="patient-main-phone"
                v-model="phonenumber"
                :items="gotpatientNames"
                dense
                filled
                append-icon=""
                hide-spin-buttons
                type="number"
                label="Phone"
              ></v-autocomplete>

              <v-autocomplete
                v-model="alternativephonenumber"
                :items="numbers"
                dense
                filled
                hide-spin-buttons
                type="number"
                append-icon=""
                label="Alternative Phone"
              ></v-autocomplete>
            </div>
          </div>
```

My array looks like this **:**

```
"patientnames": [
        {
            "userid": 1,
            "id": 1,
            "patientname": "Eadie",
            "phone": "8759800300",
            "alternativephone": "1092851519",
            "gender": "Female"
        },
        {
            "userid": 2,
            "id": 2,
            "patientname": "Banana",
            "phone": "8759800300",
            "alternativephone": "1092851519",
            "gender": "Female"
        },
        {
            "userid": 6,
            "id": 6,
            "patientname": "Alvera",
            "phone": "5352622059",
            "alternativephone": "5927226106",
            "gender": "Male"
        },
        {
            "userid": 7,
            "id": 7,
            "patientname": "Gavin",
            "phone": "1375015030",
            "alternativephone": "8917525333",
            "gender": "Male"
        },
        {
            "userid": 9,
            "id": 9,
            "patientname": "Haleigh",
            "phone": "4724336149",
            "alternativephone": "1954541209",
            "gender": "Male"
        },
        {
            "userid": 10,
            "id": 10,
            "patientname": "Eadmund",
            "phone": "5826216088",
            "alternativephone": "5209747561",
            "gender": "Female"
        }
    ]
}
```

How my UI looks :

[image]

I am not sure how to tackle this with Vue. I thought of `v-for` but it will also duplicate html elements and I don't want that.

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: You can use computed property. Did you try it?

Comment: Do you mean using computed in combination with v-ref ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, here's how you can do it.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      patientname: {
        "userid": null,
        "id": null,
        "patientname": null,
        "phone": null,
        "alternativephone": null,
        "gender": null
      },
      "patientnames": [{
          "userid": 1,
          "id": 1,
          "patientname": "Eadie",
          "phone": "8759800300",
          "alternativephone": "1092851519",
          "gender": "Female"
        },
        {
          "userid": 2,
          "id": 2,
          "patientname": "Banana",
          "phone": "8759800300",
          "alternativephone": "1092851519",
          "gender": "Female"
        },
        {
          "userid": 6,
          "id": 6,
          "patientname": "Alvera",
          "phone": "5352622059",
          "alternativephone": "5927226106",
          "gender": "Male"
        },
        {
          "userid": 7,
          "id": 7,
          "patientname": "Gavin",
          "phone": "1375015030",
          "alternativephone": "8917525333",
          "gender": "Male"
        },
        {
          "userid": 9,
          "id": 9,
          "patientname": "Haleigh",
          "phone": "4724336149",
          "alternativephone": "1954541209",
          "gender": "Male"
        },
        {
          "userid": 10,
          "id": 10,
          "patientname": "Eadmund",
          "phone": "5826216088",
          "alternativephone": "5209747561",
          "gender": "Female"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="patient-info">
      <h4>Create Appointment</h4>

      <div class="patient-create-data-container">

        <v-autocomplete class="patient-patient" v-model="patientname" :items="patientnames" hide-no-data dense filled append-icon="" item-text="patientname" label="Patient Name" return-object></v-autocomplete>

        <v-text-field v-model="patientname.gender" show-current type="text" label="Gender"></v-text-field>
      </div>

      <div class="patient-phones">
        <v-autocomplete class="patient-patient" v-model="patientname" :items="patientnames" hide-no-data dense filled append-icon="" item-text="phone" label="Phone" return-object></v-autocomplete>

        <v-text-field v-model="patientname.alternativephone" dense filled hide-spin-buttons type="number" append-icon="" label="Alternative Phone"></v-text-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>



<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```